# How to make text to be always aligned even on curved path

Tags: css, reactjs, canvas

I‘m building a "flow-builder" and I need to get this result:
[image]

Currently I have this as my edge :
[image]

As you can see the text on the edge is matching the edge itself and I need it to align differently like in the first picture

I am new to path/textPath so i cant figure this out.
Here is my "Edge" component

```
import React from 'react';
import { getSmoothStepPath, getMarkerEnd } from 'react-flow-renderer';

export default function DefaultEdge({
                                       id,
                                       sourceX,
                                       sourceY,
                                       targetX,
                                       targetY,
                                       sourcePosition,
                                       targetPosition,
                                       style = {},
                                       data,
                                       arrowHeadType,
                                       markerEndId,
                                   }) {
    const edgePath = getSmoothStepPath({ sourceX, sourceY, sourcePosition, targetX, targetY, targetPosition });
    const markerEnd = getMarkerEnd(arrowHeadType, markerEndId);

    return (
        <>
            <path id={id} style={style} className="react-flow__edge-path" d={edgePath} markerEnd={markerEnd} />
            <text>
                <textPath href={`#${id}`} style={{ fontSize: '12px' }} startOffset="90%" textAnchor="middle" >
                    {data?.text  || 'default text'}
                </textPath>
            </text>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can add to the `<text>` component a `position: absolute` and style it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged `canvas` I'll assume this is being done on a canvas. I can't help with the code you provided but can give an example of how to use the methods built in to canvas to achieve what you want.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 300;

let pt1 = {x: 50, y: 50};
let pt2 = {x: 200, y: 50};
let pt3 = {x: 230, y: 150};
let pt4 = {x: 230, y: 220};
let pt5 = {x: 230, y: 250};

let nodes = [];
class Nodes {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = 5;
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 5, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

let node1 = nodes.push(new Nodes(pt1.x, pt1.y));
let node2 = nodes.push(new Nodes(pt3.x, pt3.y));
let node3 = nodes.push(new Nodes(pt4.x, pt4.y));
let node4 = nodes.push(new Nodes(pt5.x, pt5.y));

for (let i=0;i<nodes.length;i++) {
  nodes[i].draw();
}

class Edge {
  constructor(x, y, lw) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.lw = lw;
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(pt1.x, pt1.y);
    ctx.lineTo(pt2.x, pt2.y);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(230, 50, 230, 50, 230, 80);
    ctx.lineTo(pt3.x, pt3.y);
    ctx.moveTo(pt4.x, pt4.y);
    ctx.lineTo(pt5.x, pt5.y);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

let edge1 = new Edge();

edge1.draw()

ctx.font = 'bold 20px arial';
ctx.textAlign = 'center';
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
ctx.fillText('Hello world', pt3.x, (pt3.y + pt4.y)/2);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```